# Creation of weekly calender in php

Tags: php, html, calendar

I have created a php calender which will show one week at a time.Here is the code i have created

```
 <?php
   $week = date("W");
   $year = (isset($_GET['year']))?$_GET['year']:date("Y");
   $week = (isset($_GET['week']))?$_GET['week']:Date('W');
   if($week>53){
     $year+= 1;
     $week=1;
   }
 ?>

 <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next  Week</a> <!--Next week-->

 <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Previous week-->

 <table border="1px">
 <tr>
 <td>Employee</td>
 <?php
 for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
 {
    $d = strtotime($year."W".$week.$day);                           
    echo "<td>".date('l',$d )."<br>";
    echo date('d M',$d)."</td>";
 }
 ?>
 </tr>
```

when i am trying to go to the next week it is working correctly. But when the year is changing it is not working for the next year.

Comment: How many weeks does a year have? I think it's not `if($week > 53)`

Comment: Yeah i have also tried using 54 but it is not working

Comment: Well, that's because a year has only 52 weeks.

Comment: Yaa but it is also not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Leave the week calculation to the [DateTime::setIsoDate()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) method.

Here is the simplest and best solution for your problem :

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime;
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
    $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
} else {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
}
$year = $dt->format('o');
$week = $dt->format('W');
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Previous week-->
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next Week</a> <!--Next week-->

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Employee</td>
<?php
do {
    echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>\n";
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Glavic Your code helped me a lot but a small problem
Here with your code the week is starting with MON
but I am trying to start with SUN To SAT can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `strtotime`, your week has to be **two-digit**. You have to prepend a zero, if the week is lower than 10 before the `for` loop.

```
if($week < 10) {
    $week = '0'. $week;
}
for($day = 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
```

Also, a year only has 52 weeks, the condition at the beginning should be.

```
if($week > 52) {
    $year++;
    $week = 1;
} elseif($week < 1) { // If you want the possibility to go back too
    $year--;
    $week = 52;
}
```

---

Full code:

```
<?php
$year = (isset($_GET['year'])) ? $_GET['year'] : date("Y");
$week = (isset($_GET['week'])) ? $_GET['week'] : date('W');
if($week > 52) {
    $year++;
    $week = 1;
} elseif($week < 1) {
    $year--;
    $week = 52;
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week == 52 ? 1 : 1 + $week).'&year='.($week == 52 ? 1 + $year : $year); ?>">Next  Week</a> <!--Next week-->
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week == 1 ? 52 : $week -1).'&year='.($week == 1 ? $year - 1 : $year); ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Previous week-->

<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Employee</td>
<?php
if($week < 10) {
    $week = '0'. $week;
}
for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
    $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);

    echo "<td>". date('l', $d) ."<br>". date('d M', $d) ."</td>";
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your statement `Also, a year only has 52 weeks` is incorrect. Wiki copy/paste: `In every 400 years there are 71 years with 53 weeks.`. For example, year 2009 had 53 weeks. Try `echo date('o W', strtotime('2009-12-31'));`