# Fill the calendar with unix time in php

Tags: php, unix, calendar

I'm creating a table calendar, that works on the weekly basis. The calendar looks like this

[image]

I used code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936417/629127) to set up my header dates. The code I have looks like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
$year = $dt->format('o');
$week = $dt->format('W');
$current_time = time(); 

$return .= '<table class="reservation_time_table">
                <tr><th>'.esc_html__('Hours', 'time_reservation').'</th>';
do {
    $return .= '<th>' . $dt->format('l') . '<br>' . $dt->format('d M Y') . '</th>';
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
$return .= '</tr>';
for ($hour=8; $hour < 23 ; $hour++) {
    $return .= '<tr>';
        $return .= '<th>'.$hour.':00</th>';
        for ($i=0; $i <7 ; $i++) {
            $return .= '<td data-reservation_time=""></td>';
        }
    $return .= '</tr>';
}

$return .= '</table>';
```

Now, I need to put in my `data-reservation_time` the date in `Unix` format (that's why there is `$current_time` variable), of that cell. So for instance in the cell for Friday 20 in 8:00 there should be `1448006400` in that cell. I'll use this later on to store in the database.

But how do I do that? I'm stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Found the answer. It's below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was simpler than I thought. Well I am still not 100% sure that the first part is absolutely correct, but it should be (by my logic).

First, create an array of dates for this week (curtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536802/629127))

```
$today = time();

if (date('D', $today) === 'Mon') {
    $timestamp = strtotime('this Monday');
} else{
    $timestamp = strtotime('last Monday');
}
$days = array();
$dates = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $days[] = strftime('%A <br /> %d %b %Y', $timestamp);
    $dates[] = strftime('%d %b %Y', $timestamp);
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
```

The first `if else` loop was to check if today is Monday, so that you fill the array towards the next Sunday (in the same week). If it's Tuesday, then the timestamp reference is the last Monday.

And then just do a `foreach`

```
$return .= '<table class="reservation_time_table">
                <tr><th>'.esc_html__('Hours', 'time_reservation').'</th>';
    foreach ($days as $day => $day_value) {
        $return .= '<th>'.$day_value.'</th>';
    }
    $return .= '</tr>';
    for ($hour=8; $hour < 23 ; $hour++) {
    $return .= '<tr>';
        $return .= '<th>'.$hour.':00</th>';
    foreach ($dates as $date => $date_value) {
        $full_hour = $hour. ':00';
        $return .= '<td data-time="'.strtotime($date_value. ' ' .$full_hour).'"></td>';
    }
    $return .= '</tr>';
    }
$return .= '</table>';
```

And my dates with times are in `data-time`, ripe for jquery grabbing :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unixtimstamp using strtotime:

```
<?php
$date = date("d M Y");
$time = "15:00";
$unixTime = strtotime($date . " " . $time);
?>
```

Comment: I know I can, but I need to show the date and time in the table for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$return .= '<td data-reservation_time="' . strtotime($dt->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $hour . ":00:00") . '"></td>';
```

In order to get the timestamp, get the day from your `$dt` object, and time from the loop.

Comment: This returns next week instead of the week in the table above, I tried that already :\