# Weekly Calendar minus Sunday

Tags: php, html, calendar

I got this code from here: [Creation of weekly calender in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868128/creation-of-weekly-calender-in-php)

My question is, how do I make it end up to Saturday only?

```
    <?php
    $dt = new DateTime;
    if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
        $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
    } else {
        $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
    }
    $year = $dt->format('o');
    $week = $dt->format('W');
?>

<center>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>" style="padding-right: 600px">Previous Week</a> <!--Previous week-->
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>" style="padding-left: 600px">Next Week</a> <!--Next week-->
</center>

<table border="1" style="text-align: center" align="center">
    <col width="100px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <col width="200px" />
    <tr>
        <td>Time</td>
    <?php
        do {
            echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('F d') . "</td>\n";
            $dt->modify('+1 day');
        } while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
    ?>
```

Comment: `for($day=1; $day<=5; $day++)` - (i.e. change 7 to 5) is this what you're after?

Comment: To 6 you mean. He does want Saturday. Otherwise you loose the whole weekend ;)

Comment: Hello @SergeyVidusov, sorry I posted the wrong code. Maybe you know the answer to this one? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing this:

```
do {
    echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('F d') . "</td>\n";
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
```

to this:

```
for($day=1;$day<=6;$day++){
    echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('F d') . "</td>\n";
    $dt->modify('+1 day');
}
```

:D

Comment: your answer helped me ! how to get from sunday to saturday with your getting monday to saturday can you please help me